# Getting user details who downloaded my ios app from apple app store

Tags: ios, app-store

There is requirement in my iOS application to display the list of users who are using my app. can i get this details from apple app store. if it is possible then how can i get user details (mail id, username etc) who have downloaded my app from app store.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you cannot. you have to ask the user yourself for the details

Answer (score 4):

Before fight for search anything, read this point in the Apple Review Guideline.

> 12.1 Applications that scrape any information from Apple sites (for example from apple.com, iTunes Store, App Store, iTunes Connect, Apple Developer Programs, etc) or create rankings using content from Apple sites and services will be rejected
>
> 2.25 Apps that display Apps other than your own for purchase or promotion in a manner similar to or confusing with the App Store will be rejected

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible using iTunes Connect exposed data and is against AppStore policy.

If you wish to track your users, implement an authentication API in your app, such as Facebook, Twitter, Google or your own, and require users to login before they can use the app.

Comment: Just to add to this.  Anyone looking to add an authentication login to your app, make sure it is not 'required' as a first step.  I had one rejected because i was forcing the user to login immediately.  Apple wants the app to have "basic functionality" without having to login to anything.  They should only have to login to use portions of the app that require it.